# Could someone please assist with this NDK linker error? Been working at it for hours. NDK bug?

Tags: android-ndk, linker

I am trying to compile and link a simple enough program (basically a hello world example) all day long. I've asked the author of the library and he told me to fix my linker dependencies. Here is the relevant info:

I also tried compiling with the author's build tool and linking it as a static library, but to no avail. I have also tried all variations of the STL build environment. Am I doing anything wrong, or is something else the problem?

testbgfx.cpp

```
#include <SDL.h>
#include <bgfxplatform.h>

#include <bgfx.h>

int main(int argc, char* args[])
{
// SDL_Init( SDL_INIT_EVERYTHING ); Uncommenting this did nothing
SDL_Rect bounds;
SDL_GetDisplayBounds(0,&bounds);
int height = bounds.h;
int width = bounds.w;
SDL_Window* window = SDL_CreateWindow("TestApp",SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED,SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED,width,height,SDL_WINDOW_MAXIMIZED);

bgfx_sdlSetWindow(window);


bgfx::init();

return 0;

}
```

Android.mk (for client app)

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LOCAL_MODULE := main

LOCAL_SRC_FILES := testbgfx.cpp
# Switching to static lib did nothing
#LOCAL_STATIC_LIBRARIES := bgfx
LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARIES := SDL2 bx bgfx  

# Required for compilation
LOCAL_CXXFLAGS := $(LOCAL_CFLAGS) -D__STDC_LIMIT_MACRO -D__STDC_FORMAT_MACROS -D__STDC_CONSTANT_MACROS

LOCAL_LDLIBS := -lGLESv1_CM -lGLESv2 -llog -lc -ldl -lm -landroid -lEGL

include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)

$(call import-module,bx)
$(call import-module,bgfx)
$(call import-module,SDL2)
```

The Android.mk for the bgfx library (in ndk sources directory, as required)

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LOCAL_MODULE := bgfx
#This did nothing
#LOCAL_C_INCLUDES += src

#Disabled those to see that would happen - nothing
#LOCAL_CFLAGS := -Wall -Wextra -g -Wa,--noexecstack -no-canonical-prefixes -ffunction-sections -Wno-psabi -Wunused-value -Wundef -fstack-protector
#LOCAL_CXXFLAGS := $(LOCAL_CFLAGS) -D__STDC_LIMIT_MACROS -D__STDC_FORMAT_MACROS -D__STDC_CONSTANT_MACROS -MMD -MP -fPIC -std=c++0x

LOCAL_SRC_FILES := src
LOCAL_C_INCLUDES := $(LOCAL_PATH)/include
#Enabling the following changed nothing
#LOCAL_C_INCLUDES := $(LOCAL_PATH)/3rdparty
LOCAL_EXPORT_C_INCLUDES := $(LOCAL_PATH)/include

# This doesn't work
#LOCAL_EXPORT_C_INCLUDES += $(LOCAL_PATH)/src/*.h
# Neither does this
#LOCAL_EXPORT_C_INCLUDES += $(wildcard $(LOCAL_PATH)/src/*h)


LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARIES := bx
LOCAL_EXPORT_SHARED_LIBRARIES := bx

#Switching to static did nothing
#include $(BUILD_STATIC_LIBRARY)
include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)

$(call import-modules,bx)
```

Android.mk for bx (utility lib depended on my bgfx, also in the ndk sources dir)

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)
include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE := bx 
LOCAL_EXPORT_C_INCLUDES := $(LOCAL_PATH)/include
include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

Here is relevant error log:

`/home/noob/android/android-ndk-r10d/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-    4.8/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-g++ -Wl,-soname,libmain.so -shared --sysroot=/home/noob/android/android-ndk-r10d/platforms/android-18/arch-arm ./obj/local/armeabi-v7a/objs/main/testbgfx.o ./obj/local/armeabi-v7a/libSDL2.a -lgcc ./obj/local/armeabi-v7a/libbx.so ./obj/local/armeabi-v7a/libbgfx.so ./obj/local/armeabi-v7a/libgnustl_shared.so -no-canonical-prefixes -march=armv7-a -Wl,--fix-cortex-a8  -Wl,--no-undefined -Wl,-z,noexecstack -Wl,-z,relro -Wl,-z,now -mthumb  -L/home/noob/android/android-ndk-r10d/platforms/android-18/arch-arm/usr/lib -lGLESv1_CM -lGLESv2 -llog -lc -ldl -lm -landroid -lEGL -Wl,--undefined=Java_org_libsdl_app_SDLActivity_nativeInit -ldl -lGLESv1_CM -lGLESv2 -llog -landroid /home/noob/android/android-ndk/sources/cxx-stl/gnu-libstdc++/4.8/libs/armeabi-v7a/libsupc++.a -lc -lm -o ./obj/local/armeabi-v7a/libmain.so
jni/src/testbgfx.cpp:18: error: undefined reference to 'bgfx::init(bgfx::RendererType::Enum, bgfx::CallbackI*, bx::ReallocatorI*)'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [obj/local/armeabi-v7a/libmain.so] Error 1`

Comment: and the linker error is...?

Comment: Just added it. It's the very last output of `ndk-build V=1 clean all`. The rest compiles fine.

Comment: I haven't looks at NDK in a long time, but since this is a link error, you may want to look at LOCAL_STATIC_LIBRARIES vs LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARIES. Is bfgx a ".so" file or a ".a"?

Comment: if it's a static lib(.a), you should be using LOCAL_STATIC_LIBRARIES. If it is a shared library (.so), you may want to check if you are defining the right preprocessor flags for the bgfx library so that it's functions get defined as extern.

Comment: I tried both, unfortunately. I am suspecting an NDK bug (there are plenty) but wanted to check here first.

Comment: have you checked if this file actually exists? :
./obj/local/armeabi-v7a/libbgfx.so - and if the function you're after is actually defined in the headers you're including?

Comment: Yes for both. The function has variadic arguments, if that makes a difference

Comment: is this what you're using?https://github.com/bkaradzic/bgfx/blob/master/include/bgfx.h

Comment: I don't see a header include path for bgfx in the compile string in the error you posted. If that's not it, I'm out of ideas ;)

Comment: @Colin is it possible for you to release minimal compiling demo on github maybe?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `Android.mk` for bgfx doesn't actually seem to be listing any source files to compile - you've only listed `LOCAL_SRC_FILES := src` which seems to be a directory. You need to list all the individual C/C++ source files here.

Comment: Or use something like `MY_SRC_FILES := $(wildcard $(LOCAL_PATH)/src/*.cpp) \ LOCAL_SRC_FILES := $(MY_SRC_FILES:$(LOCAL_PATH)/%=%)`

Comment: THANK YOU! This totally worked. If I had 15 reps, I'd vote this right up!

Comment: You should at least be able to mark the answer as accepted, even if you don't have 15 rep though.

Comment: Done! Glad to give back in any small way possible :) Also, to bitwise and Michael, thank you for the time you took to help.